# Tensorflow slow inference speed in a loop

Tags: tensorflow, reinforcement-learning

I am working on a reinforcement learning implementation using Tensorflow. After profiling on the training procedure, I found something really weird:

The following code is in a training loop:

```
    state_batch, \
    action_batch, \
    reward_batch, \
    next_state_batch, \
    is_episode_finished_batch = self.data_manager.get_next_batch()

    state_batch = np.divide(state_batch, 10.0)
    next_state_batch = np.divide(next_state_batch, 10.0)

    # Calculate y for the td_error of the critic
    y_batch = []

    next_action_batch = self.actor_network.target_evaluate(
        next_state_batch, action_batch)

    q_value_batch = self.critic_network.target_evaluate(
        next_state_batch, next_action_batch)

    for i in range(0, self.batch_size):
        if is_episode_finished_batch[i]:
            y_batch.append([reward_batch[i]])
        else:
            y_batch.append(reward_batch[i] + GAMMA * q_value_batch[i])

    # Now that we have the y batch, train the critic
    self.critic_network.train(y_batch, state_batch, action_batch)

    # Then get the action gradient batch and adapt the gradient with the gradient inverting method
    action_batch_for_gradients = self.actor_network.evaluate(
        state_batch, action_batch)

    q_gradient_batch = self.critic_network.get_action_gradient(
        state_batch, action_batch_for_gradients)

    q_gradient_batch = self.grad_inv.invert(
        q_gradient_batch, action_batch_for_gradients)

    # Now we can train the actor
    self.actor_network.train(q_gradient_batch, state_batch, action_batch)
```

`actor_network` and `critic_network` are two classes that implement actor and critic in actor-critic algorithm. Each of them has their own network and operations, but all in the same graph and will run within the same session. Each of the member function (like evaluate, train...) contains a session.run and feed the data they need by passing parameter.

I observed that `action_batch_for_gradients` runs extremely slow, taking 0.x seconds to do one inference, even much slower than the `self.critic_network.train`. `action_batch_for_gradients` is simply an inference operation in actor network to get action. I then copy this line and duplicate it and found that only the first `action_batch_for_gradients`, right after `self.critic_network.train` is slow, but the second one is of the normal speed of a forward operation. I think it has something to do with switching within a graph, between training a network and forward in another network. But I can't tell how to avoid.

I found some discussions on stackoverflow about using same graph in the loop, instead of building new ones each time, to speed up using tensorflow. But I already build the graph beforehand and only run the different part of the graph in the training loop. So I don't know how i wrongly use tensorflow on this loop training. I am using Tensorflow 1.6.

I would appreciate your help!